# WPF application throwing Win32Exception: Attempt to access invalid address

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I have a WPF kiosk application running on Windows 8 and from time to time, often after several hours, the application throws an exception on the CurrentDomain.

The application uses some timers to update an onscreen clock and network connection indicators. The corresponding event handlers already have try..catch blocks.

I've got an exception handler attached to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException that sends me the exception's stack trace by mail as follows.

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Tentativa de acessar endereço inválido

Source: WindowsBase
NativeErrorCode: 487
ErrorCode: -2147467259

  em MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetWindowText(HandleRef hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, Int32 nMaxCount)
  em System.Windows.Automation.Peers.WindowAutomationPeer.GetNameCore()
  em System.Windows.Automation.Peers.AutomationPeer.UpdateSubtree()
  em System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireAutomationEvents()
  em System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
  em System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
  em System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
  em System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
  em System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
  em System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
  em System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
  em MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
  em System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
  em System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
  em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
  em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
  em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
  em System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
  em System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
  em System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
  em MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
  em MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
  em System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
  em MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
  em System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
  em MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
  em MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
  em System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
  em System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
  em System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
  em System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
  em System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
  em System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
  em MyApplication.Forms.App.Main()
```

I have added exception handlers all over the code, but I'm still not able to catch the exception. I've looked at the .NET Framework source code and found the implementation of GetNameCore() but I still don't know what might be causing the problem.

```
[SecurityCritical,SecurityTreatAsSafe]
override protected string GetNameCore()
{ 
    string name = base.GetNameCore();

    if(name == string.Empty) 
    {
        Window window = (Window)Owner; 

        if(!window.IsSourceWindowNull)
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(512);
            UnsafeNativeMethods.GetWindowText(new HandleRef(null, window.CriticalHandle), sb, sb.Capacity); 
            name = sb.ToString(); 

            if (name == null) 
                name = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    return name;
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas where this exception might come from and how to avoid it?

Comment: As nobody could help me and I was not able to find out why this exception is thrown, I am now catching and ignoring it in the `Application.Current.Dispatcher.UnhandledException` and `Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException` event handlers.